# Update All Rows in SQL with One Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update all rows, for example;

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column= '0'
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.....)
```

It goes like this, i can write id by manually, but i want like this;

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column= '0'
WHERE id IN (ALL)
```

Are there any query?

Answer (score 2):

This should update all rows:

```
UPDATE table_name
    SET column = '0';
```

The `WHERE` clause is not needed.

I should note that MySQL has a "safety" mode called `SQL_SAFE_UPDATES` which only allows `UPDATE` statements with a `WHERE` clause.  You may need to disable this:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
```

Or use:

```
WHERE id >= 0
```

or some similar logic that will select all ids.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=61b121a1a00e014889581a85e0eb508f) is a db<>fiddle that illustrates this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update all rows just don't use any `WHERE` clause at all.

```
UPDATE table_name
       SET column = '0';
```